# How to add a icon before My Account in magento toplinks?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a toplinks in header Magento. I want to add a different icon for "My Account  My Cart  My Wishlist  Login" toplink menus. Please help me with step by step procedure. I am a beginner for magento.
Thanks

Comment: you can set using css .header .links li

Comment: Sounds like this is a custom template. Please provide the name and a link of this template.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into admin panel ange go to `System > Configuration > Developer > Debug`
2. Set `Template Path Hints to Yes` and then `save the config`
3. Now goto frontend and refresh the page. So you can see template path hints. (Make sure you  have disabled the cache. If not just goto admin panel `System > Cache Management` and refresh cache )
4. Now you can see what is the template file responsible for loading top links. `(app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml )`
5. So now you can do your modifications.

Comment: It might be nicer if you don't have to change the general template, but I have no better idea either :-/

Comment: change 'base' for the package you are using and 'default' to the template name. example: app\design\frontend\my_package\my_template_name\template\page\template\links.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is an old question, but for those who bumps by and still wondering:

The easiest way is to add a :before tag in your css file, with a content tag.

Lets say you want an icon in front of the wishlist link:

.header a[href*="wishlist"]:before, .top-line a[href*="wishlist"]:before, .link-wishlist:before {
content: "//";
}

This will echo // My wishlist on your store.
Its best to use an icon-pack for this tho, so I suggest you search for a good one, and include it in your base css file.